# R Applying different functions to different data frame columns

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to develop a reusable solution to the following problem.

I will have various data frames and I wish to define some basic functions and then apply these functions to the various columns in the data frame. The result would be a data frame that has the same number of rows and columns as the original data frame.

I want this solution to be reusable insofar that different combinations of functions can be applied to different data frames.

Its a bit tricky to explain this in words.  I am hoping the code below will make the above a bit clearer.

```
# construct an example data frame
v_a <- c(1, 4, 8, 10, 12)
v_b <- c(4, 6, 7, 4, 3)
v_c <-  c(10, 23, 45, 12, 45)
v_d <- c(12, 45, 7, 10, 5)

df <- data.frame(a = v_a, b = v_b, c = v_c, d = v_d)

# define some example functions
fn_1 <- function(x) x * 3
fn_2 <- function(x) x * 4


# assemble functions into a vector
vct_functions <- c(fn_1, fn_2, fn_1, fn_1)

# apply vector of functions to columns in a data.frame
new_df <- fn_apply_functionList(df, vct_functions)
```

I am hoping to reuse the solution above such that a different combination of functions could be applied to the same or a different data frame.

Again, the following is a code snippet to make this clearer.

```
# create another vector of functions
vct_functionsB <- c(fn_3, fn_4, fn_1, fn_2)

# apply vector of functions to columns in a data.frame
new_df <- fn_apply_functionList(another_df, vct_functions)
```

Any ideas on an elegant solution would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you have 2+ objects of the same length to loop along, use `Map` or `mapply` - `df[] <- Map(function(d,f) f(d), df, vct_functions)` for example.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the Map() solution is passing two sets of of arguments to a function.  I want to apply a vector of n functions to n lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@geotheory was almost there, `vct_functionsB` is coerced to a `list`

Try this,

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(1:ncol(df), function(c) vct_functions[[c]](df[, c])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this..?

```
lapply(1:ncol(df), FUN=function(i){vct_functionsB[i](df[,i])})
```

And then unlist/parse the results..

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I thought it would work but when I tried it....I received the following message:  "error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : attempt to apply non-function"  mmmm??

Comment: Pretty sure it's because `vct_functionsB[i]` should be `vct_functionsB[[i]]`.  Check `list(function(x) x)[1](5)` against `list(function(x) x)[[1]](5)`

Comment: The single brackets [] return a list while the double brackets return a single element.