# Apply different functions to data frame columns depending on the column names matching a pattern

Tags: r

Given a data frame:

```
l$`__a` <- data.frame(`__ID` = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), 
col = stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 1), check.names = F )
```

And two supporting functions:

```
prefixColABC <- function(dfCol) {
paste0("ABC_", dfCol)
}

prefixColDEF <- function(dfCol) {
  paste0("DEF_", dfCol)
}
```

**How can I apply the first function for data frame column names staring with `__` and the second for all other columns?**

To solve this problem, I thought I would subset first all columns with names starting with `__`, apply `prefixColABC` to them, then subset all others and apply `prefixColDEF` to them. Then I would use `cbind()` to put all of the columns together into one data frame again.

Here's some of my progress:

Here's how the first function can be applied to all columns:

```
as.data.frame( apply(l$`__a`, 2, prefixColABC) )
```

And here's how I can subset the columns. All with column names starting with `__`:

```
l$`__a`[ grep(pattern = "^__", l$`__a`), 1 ]
```

I don't know how to subset all other columns that don't match this pattern. And I don't know how to set up the condition inside the apply statement

I think this question is similar to mine, but does not select the columns based on matching a pattern:
[R Applying different functions to different data frame columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278405/r-applying-different-functions-to-different-data-frame-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this assuming that the input data frame is called `dd`:

```
hasPrefix <- grepl("^__", names(dd))
dd[, hasPrefix] <- lapply(dd[, hasPrefix, drop = FALSE], prefixColABC)
dd[, !hasPrefix] <- lapply(dd[, !hasPrefix, drop = FALSE], prefixColDEF)
```

giving:

```
> dd
    __ID   col
1  ABC_G DEF_x
2  ABC_n DEF_U
3  ABC_c DEF_G
4  ABC_O DEF_X
5  ABC_p DEF_E
6  ABC_U DEF_j
7  ABC_M DEF_G
8  ABC_0 DEF_l
9  ABC_V DEF_i
10 ABC_B DEF_u
```

**Note:** The input `dd`, prior to modification, is:

```
dd <- structure(list(`__ID` = structure(c(4L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 
1L, 10L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "B", "c", "G", "M", "n", "O", "p", 
"U", "V"), class = "factor"), col = structure(c(8L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("E", "G", "i", "j", "l", 
"u", "U", "x", "X"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("__ID", "col"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your solution is extremely helpful, thanks! I'm trying to adapt it not to overwrite the original data frame. Could you help me with this too? I'm attempting now to create an empty data frame with the same structure in this way: `dd2 <- dd[0,]` and then fill it with data from the `apply` command, but I'm getting this error "replacement element 1 has 10 rows to replace 0 rows". Should I instead use `vapply` to make sure that I always get a column vector to insert into the data frame?

Comment: I've also tried to write a function which uses your example, but it's not returning a data frame with two columns as I expected. Do you have any hints about this to give?  

`processOneDF <- function (dfName){
  dfName["__ID"] <- lapply(dfName[, "__ID", drop = FALSE], prefixColABC)
  dfName["col"] <- lapply(dfName[, "col", drop = FALSE], prefixColDEF)
}

l5<- l
l5$`__a`<- processOneDF(l5$`__a`)`